# Windows: Separate Previews for Separated Taskbar Icons?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Our desktops at work were switched to Windows 7 a few months ago but I still can't get it to function quite like I want it to.

I have fixed the alt-tab to work like it did before and have configured the task bar to look almost like the old one.

The only thing I can't get to work is suppose you have two instances of the same application, they are separate icons on the start bar that look pretty much like they did before (so far so good) but if you hover over either task bar item, Aero will show a preview of both instances.

What I would like is for Aero to only show a preview of the item I am actually hovering over.

Comment: heheh people are busy trying to make Windows 8.1 act like Windows 7, and you're still trying to make Windows 7 act like Windows 2000.  Man are you in for a world of hurt when you get Windows 8. ;)

Comment: I removed your second question regarding the Start Menu's appearance.  If you'd still like to ask it, please post it as its own question.

Answer (score 1):

[7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) has some great options for customizing the taskbar. It will allow you to place new windows which are opened for an existing application *next to* the existing windows in the taskbar, but without actually *combining* them. The end result is that there's a little more space between them (since they aren't grouped), but they each get their own aero preview (and in addition, you can move them around individually instead of only being able to move the whole group).